# Identifying pairs records & setting up flags for them in db2

Tags: sql, select, db2

I want to identify pair records & set up flags for them in a query:
Requirement is as below:

Customer table.

```
account_id trasact_id   buysellflag
11           1212        S
12           1212        B
13           1212        S
54           4545        S
89           4875        B
```

For multiple accounts there are same transact_ids. I want to set up a flag if there are two buysell flags (B & S) for the same trasact_id. As for 1212 transact_id there are 3 records of buysell - same transact_id & different buysell flag. So for 1212 there is 1 pair & 1 orphan record. As there are 2 'S' flags for 1212 transact_id we can select any 1 record (there is no condition to select which 'S' to select)

```
account_id trasact_id   buysellflag     
11           1212        S                 
12           1212        B               
13           1212        S
```

Then flag should set up as follows:

```
account_id trasact_id   buysellflag     transact_flag
11           1212        S                 1
12           1212        B                 1
13           1212        S                 0
54           4545        S                 0
89           4875        B                 0
```

This is in DB2 database.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with the transact_flag?  What is the goal?

Comment: Can there be multiple buyer-seller pairs for the same trasact_id? For example, if there was an additional row containing (14, 1212, 'B'), would you want to see transact_flag = 1 for both buyer-seller pairs (11+12 and 13+14)?

Comment: And which version of DB2/which platform?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements/conditions are not completely clear.

Here is some SQL you can try:

```
update TEST as t1
set transact_flag = 1
where transact_flag = 0
and 
(
 (
 buysellflag = 'S'
 and account_id = (select min(account_id) from TEST as t2 where transact_flag = 0 and buysellflag = 'S' and t2.transact_id = t1.transact_id) 
 and 0 < (select count(*) from TEST as t3 where transact_flag = 0 and buysellflag = 'B' and t3.transact_id = t1.transact_id)
 ) or (
 buysellflag = 'B' 
 and account_id = (select min(account_id) from TEST as t3 where transact_flag = 0 and buysellflag = 'B' and t3.transact_id = t1.transact_id) 
 and 0 < (select count(*) from TEST as t4 where transact_flag = 0 and buysellflag = 'S' and t4.transact_id = t1.transact_id)
 )
)
```

If it is possible to have multiple pairs for one transact_id, you will have to keep executing it until there are no updates.